# StringReplacement with User's Input - Java

Tags: java

I am not sure if I am going about this correctly.  I am writing a program that exercises that StringReplacement.  What were the user input's I want to be able to take one of there words and change it to something else as the output.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringReplace {


private static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String Line;
    input = new Scanner( System.in );       
    System.out.print("Please Enter a String: ");
    Line=input.next();

    Line = Line.replace("Wake", "Wake Business");

}
}
```

So for example after running the program the user is prompted to

```
Please Enter a String:
```

I would enter "Wake up America" and when I hit enter nothing happens.  I know I am going about this the wrong way and not sure how to correct it.  Yes, I am a beginner.  Would someone help me with this problem?  I would appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: After you set `Line` to the string with the replacement word, perhaps it would help if you actually do something with it?  Like, maybe, *output* it?

Comment: try to print the line after you replace it: System.out.println(Line);

Comment: Huh? What do you expect to happen? If you want something to happen, you need to write code that makes it happen.

Comment: Duh! Make's sense.  Yes, It would help to println it out.  Ok I did that but it is not printing the rest of the line as in my example of entered string. "Wake up America"  it is printing out "Wake Business".  Any more suggestions? Please

Answer (score 1):

You must print out the line to console in order to see it. Java will hold your hand to some extent, but not that far.

After you run operations on variable `Line` (`Line` should be under-case as a variable btw) you should perform this which will print out your variable.

```
   System.out.println(Line);
```

Comment: Ok, I added this "System.out.println(line);" but it is not adding the rest of the string that the user inputted.

Comment: You aren't reading in the whole `String`. After you print "Please enter in a String" you need to call `Line = input.nextLine()` so you get the whole `String` the user inputted.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, the standard delimiter of the `Scanner` class is a white space, therefore's only capturing the first part (Wake).

Use `input.useDelimiter("\n");` before you call the `next()` method and it will be solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read an entire line use 'input.nextLine'

To output to standard output use "System.out.println()"

so you can modify your code like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String line;
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please Enter a String: ");
    line = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);

    line = line.replace("Wake", "Wake Business");
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: Silly me, changing the delimiter for the newline feed character when there's actually a `nextLine()` method :) Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Java a variable never starts with a capital because classes are the only thing that you start to write with a capital letter, so you reffer to a class...
use this instead for your variable name:

```
String line;
```

and add this to your code @ the end:

```
System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: Ok, but how do I get the rest of the string to print out?

Comment: Because you do a String.replace you replace the String with another String, so the other one goes lost. Then you do at the end of your code System.out.println(line), here you print your String to the console box where you entered your String. Thats should end your code. ;-)

Comment: oh and it's not: System.out.print it's System.out.println ;-), edit that in your code.

Comment: @JonasLibbrecht, using `replace()` will not replace the entire string or make the other one goes lost. It will replace only the given pattern with the given string.

Answer (score -1):

Your error was in the uppercase letter of `Line`.

Try this (it works):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringReplace {    

private static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String line; //Your problem was here
    input = new Scanner( System.in );       
    System.out.print("Please Enter a String: ");
    line = input.nextLine(); //and here

    line = line.replace("Wake", "Wake Business"); //and here
    System.out.println(line);
}
}
```

Comment: Using lower-case letters for variables is a convention, not a language rule.  Using `Line` as a variable should still work unless there are other bugs.

Comment: Actually no. It's understandable she is wrong by naming a variable with a upper-case starting pnemonic, but it's not the reason of her error nor question.

Comment: I know that is a convention, but I only change that and it works... (you can test). I don't know why, but it is functionality. Maybe she has her IDE configured to don't allow upper-case on variables, because is more than a simple convention.

Comment: The program worked from the start, the issue in the end was that the string was not being read complete... Even if you hadn't changed the uppercase L of Line, the code will print "Wake Business" at the end. It's  convention and it's a very healthy one, but that don't mean that your code will not work if you don't follow it.

Comment: Ok, I've just tested. I thought the program doesn't works at the start so for that I test it (changing to lower-case) and it works, but I didn't test the program of the start :P

Comment: I just tested it and yes, you were right with the lower-case 'l' in the String variable.  I appreciate the help, guys.